# PostgreSQL & regexp_split_to_array + unnest

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

I've that kind of string

> Test 1|new york| X, Test 2| chicago|Y, Test 3| harrisburg, pa| Z

My required result it's

```
 Column1  Column 2     Column3
 Test 1   new york        X
 Test 2   chicago         Y
 Test 3   harrisburg,pa   Z
```

But running this query

```
SELECT  
split_part(stat.st, '|', 1) Column1,
split_part(stat.st, '|', 2) Column2,    
split_part(stat.st, '|', 3) Column3
FROM
(
    SELECT
            UNNEST (
                string_to_array('Test 1|new york| X, Test 2| chicago|Y, Test 3| harrisburg, pa| Z',',')
            )
         AS st
) stat;
```

Result is

```
 Column1  Column 2   Column3
 Test 1   new york      X
 Test 2   chicago       Y
 Test 3   harrisburg    
 pa          Z
```

Column3 could be everything (except | ). Possible pattern to match it's .This could be repeated N times. STRING could be everything except | char.

How could I use `regexp_split_to_array()` to have my desire result set?

Comment: You are not giving enough information.  Is column3 always a single upper case character? What else can you tell uas?

Comment: No Column3 could be everything (except | ). Possible pattern to match it's <STRING|STRING|STRING,>.This could be repeated N times. STRING could be everything except | char.

Comment: This kind of information has to be in the question. Please edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *barely enough information* to make this work. But this does the job:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab3(
   $$
   SELECT (rn/3)::text AS x, (rn%3)::text, item
   FROM  (
      SELECT row_number() OVER () - 1 AS rn, trim(item) AS item
      FROM (
         SELECT CASE WHEN rn%2 = 1 THEN regexp_split_to_table(item, ',') 
                     ELSE item END AS item
         FROM  (
            SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn, *
            FROM regexp_split_to_table('Test 1|new york| X, Test 2| chicago|Y, Test 3| harrisburg, pa| Z', '\|') AS item
            ) x
         ) y
      ) z
   $$)
```

Returns:

```
 row_name | category_1 |   category_2   | category_3
----------+------------+----------------+------------
 0        | Test 1     | new york       | X
 1        | Test 2     | chicago        | Y
 2        | Test 3     | harrisburg, pa | Z
```

After splitting the string at `|`,  I build on the criterion that only lines with *uneven row number* shall be split at `,`.
I `trim()` the results and add derivatives of another `row_number()` to arrive at this intermediary state before doing the cross tabulation:

```
 x | text |      item
---+------+----------------
 0 | 0    | Test 1
 0 | 1    | new york
 0 | 2    | X
 1 | 0    | Test 2
 1 | 1    | chicago
 1 | 2    | Y
 2 | 0    | Test 3
 2 | 1    | harrisburg, pa
 2 | 2    | Z
```

Finally, I apply the `crosstab3()` function from the [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) module. To install it, if you haven't already:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

#### Pre-process with `regexp_replace()`

Here is an alternative that may be easier to comprehend. Not sure which is faster. Complex regular expressions tend to be expensive:

```
SELECT trim(split_part(a,'|', 1)) AS column1
      ,trim(split_part(a,'|', 2)) AS column2
      ,trim(split_part(a,'|', 3)) AS column3
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(
             string_to_array(
                         regexp_replace('Test 1|new york| X, Test 2| chicago|Y, Test 3| harrisburg, pa| Z'
                        ,'([^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^,]*),', '\1~^~', 'g'), '~^~')) AS a
   ) sub
```

This one replaces commas (`,`) only after two pipes (`|`), before proceeding.
Now using `*` instead of `+` to allow for empty strings between the pipes.

Comment: Please check your answer. I've tried that, but result it's different.<pre> 0 T e s
1 t  1
2 | n e
3 w  y
4 o r k
5 |  X
6   
7 T e s
8 t  2
9 |  c
10 h i c
11 a g o
12 | Y ,
13  T e
14 s t 
15 3 | 
16 h a r
17 r i s
18 b u r
19 g , 
20 p a |
21  Z
</pre>

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: I have tested with PostgreSQL 9.1 before I posted. I can reproduce my result. You may need to set [`standard_conforming_strings = on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) - which is on by default in 9.1.

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: It's a kind of ... ;)

Comment: Last Solution it's amazing! Could you "repair" it for cases like this '||,' or 'Magic||'    ?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: I believe I did now.