# How to put values starting from the right side into columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, postgresql, split

Previous question: [Split comma separated values into target table with fixed number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291134)

Example:

```
a1, b1, c1
a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2
a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3, g3, h3, i3, j3
a4
a5, b5, c5
'
'
'
```

Output I got with help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291540/3984221:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
---------------
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 
f2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
f3 g3 h3 i3 j3
a4
a5 b5 c5
'
'
'
```

As you can see, output columns are filled from left to right.

Expected output is filling the output from right to left:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
------------------
        c1  b1  a1
```

Comment: @S-Man Hello. I upvoted every user but SO says your vote cannot be shown but it will be counted. I do appreciate the efforts of others. Answer by Erwin Brandstetter is accepted. The output requirement is given by him only.

Comment: OK :) As I can see, the answer is not been accepted. Did you click the hook at the top left corner of the answer?

Comment: @S-Man Yes. Apologies, I am new so didn't know. :)

Comment: No problems, that's why we offer guidance :) I see, you should have enough reputation now to do real upvotes as well :)

Comment: @S-Man Yes, I noticed that. Will do that. But could you please solve my query. How to print values from the right side. Thank You.

Comment: Does the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name not work? What is wrong with it? Tell him in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229090/discussion-between-martin2000-and-s-man).